# How to get around implementing internal interface with public class

Tags: kotlin

I want to have an interface/abstract class `B` that requires implementers `A` to have a public constructor and also implement bunch of internal only members. So that other modules can construct `A` but cannot use the internal methods on it.

Some of the internal members represent funcionality that is common with other classes in this module, so I created an interface `I` for them to allow composition and use in functions like `useI`.

Also I can't make `I` an abstract class because it is used on classes that already have super and multiple inheritance is not possible in Kotlin.

I have came up with this, but it is not working, because members of implemented interface are public and I cannot change that. I could make `I` public but that would mean exposing lots of internal types & stuff as public (pretty much all of the module actually), which should not be of any concern to the other modules.

```
public abstract class B : I {

    internal abstract fun doStuff()
}

internal interface I {
    fun doOtherStuff()
}

public class A : B() {
    internal override fun doStuff() {
        // ...
    }

    internal override fun doOtherStuff() { // This is not possible in kotlin?
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
internal fun useI(i: I) = ...
useI(A())
```

It seems strange to me that something like this is just no possible such high language as Kotlin, so what am I missing? How should I do it?

Comment: How does `B` in your code "require implementers A to have a public constructor"? I don't think that is possible at all.

Comment: @Sweeper Hmmm, you are right it isn't a requirement exactly. [I got it from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409640/kotlin-interface-constructor), but reading it again now, it just guarantees call of the primary constructor, not visibility, which is pretty pointless with empty constructor. But as far as the question is concerned it isn't really an issue cause I would have to actively hide the constructor for it not to work, which is fine with me.

**Edit:** But again, it is really strange to me that stuff like this is just not possible in kotlin

Comment: It's not strange if you consider the fact that one of Kotlin's main goals is to 100% interop with Java. This limits what Kotlin can do. Back to your question, there are just no internal interface members, but I think this is a feature that technically could have been added. If you want to keep the internal visibility, `A` and `B` cannot implement `I`. Since the purpose of `I` is to just group common internal methods together, how about adding a `internal abstract fun asI(): I` in `B`?  `A` can return an instance of a private inner class that implements `I`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. According to the [Kotlin Language Specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#interface-declaration), interface members must all be public.

> - All interface member properties and functions are implicitly public;
>
>   - Trying to declare a non-public member property or function in an interface is an compile-time error;

So no, this is not possible. `A` and `B` cannot implement `I` if you want their methods to be `internal`.

Since the purpose of the interface `I` is just to group together common functionalities, you can work around this using composition. Instead of `A` and `B` directly implementing `I`, they can have a property named `common` (or perhaps a better name) of type `I`, and `B` can require `A` to implement `commonProperties`.

```
abstract class B {
    internal abstract val common: I
    internal abstract fun doStuff()
}
```

`A` can implement this using an `object`:

```
class A private constructor(): B() {
    override val commonProperties = object: I {
        override fun doOtherStuff() {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }

    override fun doStuff() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can access almost everything in `A` in the `object`, so you can just move the implementations of those common functionalities into the `object`.

Instead of `useI(A())`, you'd say `useI(A().common)` instead.