# (java) Making sure a specific constructor exists for a plugin factory

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, factory

Neither interfaces nor abstract classes can dictate to subclasses the kind of constructor to implement (see [How can I force a Constructor to be defined in all subclass of my abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164334/how-can-i-force-a-constructor-to-be-defined-in-all-subclass-of-my-abstract-class))

Now I have an interface that is implemented by many subclasses. The program discovers these sub-classes at runtime through reflection.
I'd like to have a plugin factory that instantiate them ([see here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=19B52069B08BD3E7055D5C8AE67C8AE7?Id=237) for an example).

The problem is that all examples assume that all subclasses have a specific type of constructor (no arguments, for example). But I can't really be sure about this.
Since I can't enforce subclasses to have a specific constructor what should I do to avoid runtime errors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since you employ reflection, you can use [getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) (sorry, cannot paste a link to the method JavaDoc) to see if the ctor is there, and if it is, call it with specific arguments.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am doing now. But if such constructor is not specified what do I do but throw an exception?

That is, if I expect a no-args constructor and all reflection finds is constructors with arguments I have honestly no idea what the factory should do but crash

Comment: Yes, it should crash -- or rather, throw an exception of some kind. These are the tradeoffs of using reflection.